# Optimal way to survive nuclear winter?

Tags: internal-consistency, post-apocalypse, survival, nuclear-war, nuclear-winter

In my world, a global thermonuclear Third World War happens, causing a nuclear winter that will last around 5 years, coupled with radioactive fallout permeating the world.

Here’s the thing: I want to have surviving humans to “post-apocalypse” a bit, **but**, this nuclear war would most likely kill many of the humans on the surface. So my question is, what are some ways for humans to survive the war?

- The Survivors have to mostly be in North America (mainly the West Coast/Southwest parts)
- I’m looking for solutions that will allow at least a few tens of thousands of people too survive, in health.
- They have to survive the nuclear winter and radiation for 5-10 years

Comment: At the moment, this feels like a request for an [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) vs. a [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609). Can you help us out by providing more details (such as exactly where the survivors need to be, how many there are, how long they'd have to survive, etc.) and some criteria for how you'll judge the best answer? Remember, you need to be specific. Trying to leave it open-ended because what you're really doing is fishing for ideas would make it off-topic.

Comment: "*The Survivors have to mostly be in North America*" - Why? What does North America have that India, Australia, South Africa or wherever else doesn't?

Comment: Looking that you edited the question as a response to @JBH comment, I suggest you to tell "*The survivors I'm interested in knowing more detail lives in North America (mainly the West Coast/Southwest parts)*" - This way, you take no compromise in telling that North America was more surviveable than anywhere else in the world, as long as the nuclear winter have a global scale and all locations are more or less equally badly affected, so it is not a matter of just choosing the correct place of the globe to be.

Comment: @VictorStafusa DT's location makes the question more answerable. It doesn't suggest that there wouldn't be survivors elsewhere. Good questions have limitations and restrictions to keep answers from expanding out of control.  DT picked a location. Cheers. If you don't like the location, don't answer the question - but don't complain, either. You may someday ask a Q limiting answers to your hometown. How would you feel if people complained about that? (I'm especially worried about your egregious assumption that DT thinks no one else would survive. How weird.)

Comment: DT, let me ask for one more thing. How much time before the apocalypse doe the survivors have? A week or less excludes constructing a solution. A year or more almost guarantees a constructed solution. If you're allowing construction, what are the resource limitations? ("Money is no object" doesn't help. I can always dig a deep enough hole and fill it with enough resources to last as long as I want.)

Comment: @VictorStafusa I apologize for writing a second comment, but I'm very bothered by your comments. You seem to believe DT was making some kind of judgement against the world by picking a location in the U.S. There are many reasons why DT may have chosen that location none of which are in any way prejudicial. IMO your comments skirt the [Code of Conduct](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/conduct). Please accept my recommendation that if you can't think of a reason why an OP's chosen location won't work in an answer that you keep your prejudices to yourself.

Comment: Sorry, but it has to be pointed out. All the Worlds current nuclear powers are located in the Northern Hemisphere with the US being one of the two nuclear powers with the most weapons. How then do you expect 'most' of the survivors of a nuclear war to be located in the North American continent?  Its simply not not a realistic.  There would certainly be survivors in the US but they would be vastly outnumbered by those south of the equator simply because there aren't enough priority targets in the south to warrant the kind of bombardment that would leave the majority of survivors in the north.

Comment: @JBH Gosh, you're overreacting. It is because if North America (or Africa, or India or wherever else) is special, then it should have a reason for being so. However, since this restriction was added in an edit to address your concerns, I don't think that it is because the OP wants North America to have anything special, it was just because he/she/they wanted to localize the issue. However, the text as the OP wrote implies that North America have something special and I don't think that it is what he/she/they intended. And if I'm wrong afterall, the question deserves a clearer redaction anyway.

Comment: My point relates to targeting. The vast majority of the weapons (depending on what % of the arsenal is launched before hostilities cease) are going to be targeted at locations in the Northern Hemisphere - where the weapons and related systems are located. Not the South where they aren't. So the US will always be hit harder than somewhere (read anywhere) in the South.  You can certainly write a story about survivors in the locations mentioned (lots of people have). But they simply won't be the majority of survivors, they literally can't be - not in any kind of realistic setting.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple big problems:

- The North American west/southwest has lots and lots of strategic targets. Many of them are in places you might not expect, like Yakima, WA (military base and fissile material storage) or Hawthorne, NV (munitions depot). Lots of these targets, like Portland, OR, are also natural chokepoints for transport -- alternative routes around these location may be quite onerous.
- A *nuclear winter* has three main components: 1) Cold, wintry conditions...even out of season. 2) Diminished sunlight reaching the ground. 3) Widespread contamination. This means that northern fertile valleys in the Columbia/Snake watershed are likely too far north (and cold) to be worth farming. It also means that vast amounts of contamination will wash out to sea, likely making many seafoods inedible for during this time. Finally, California's Central Valley is a notorious trap for airborne pollutants, it's likely to also trap airborne contaminants.

However, you only need a few tens of thousands of survivors. So you don't need a city. You just need the equivalent of a rural county or two with a fairly warm climate, a reliable water supply, and just enough arable land.

Here are a few options to talk over with your realtor:

**San Luis Obispo County, CA**: Current population 200,000+. Fed by a small watershed without any strategic targets in it, this seaside county gets a Mediterranean climate from the Pacific Ocean to moderate the cold. However, there are military bases to the north and south just outside the county, so it's going to be a bit isolated until they stop glowing.

**Doña Ana County, NM**: Current population 200,000+. Fed by the Rio Grande upstream of El Paso, the climate is mild in winter though a bit on the hot side in summer. Several major military installations are just downstream and downwind, and it's possible that these survivors will seriously consider becoming Mexican citizens, since little there was nuked and they are quite close.

**Iron County, UT**: Current population 45,000+. More remote, more sparse, less water and a more severe winter climate. It's downwind from many strategic targets...but it's also several hundred miles away and at a much higher altitude than those low-country targets. An arid climate, it gets some snow, but not too much and it melts early. This one is more of a fixer-upper, and you will need to play with the prevailing winds and seasons to prevent initial contamination.

...or your survivors can just migrate south, and return north a few years later when things have settled down.

Answer (score 0):

**Who fights your fictional WWIII?**

40 years ago, one would have guessed on an all-out exchange between the United States and the Soviet Union, with tactical weapons falling on Europe and Japan. That would have made it *difficult* to have most survivors in the Western US, and not in New Zealand, or Africa, or South America.
These days the ready arsenals are smaller. They are probably targeted at a mix of [counterforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterforce) and [countervalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countervalue) targets. Both Seattle and [Kitsap (Bangor)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_Base_Kitsap) will be on the list.

**How lethal would an all-out nuclear exchange be today?**

As mentioned the arsenals are smaller today, and there will still be multiple weapons on the same target. The rubble of Moscow, Washington, or [Barksdale AFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barksdale_Air_Force_Base) would be rearranged by several hits. The radiological and climate effects would be *bad* on a national and global scale, but would they be an extinction-level event?

Are you prepared to introduce a complex *future history* which turns the Pacific parts of the United States into a *strategic backwater?*

Alternatively, assume that nuclear arsenals are still (or again) at Cold War levels, and that *only* the United States has effective fallout shelters with supplies for a decade. The Swiss were well known for their civil defense programs, but at best that would have meant [dying a few weeks later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonnenberg_Tunnel#Civil_defence_shelter) than the rest. Assume that the Americans have real long-term shelters for a significant number of people.

For a really weird explanation, assume that civil defense preparations were insufficient all over the world, including the US, but that only in the US **people refused to enter the bunkers:** conspiracy theorists went crazy when the order came, talked people out of it. That leaves 100 or 500 people (the assigned technical staff and a few who believed in the warnings) in a bunker that should have supplied 10,000 survivors for a two months, so they can stay in much longer than designed. 100 bunkers like that and you have your target population.